# Is it possible to create a dynamic page using design from adobe muse?

Tags: php, codeigniter, web, adobe, muse

I want to know if is it possible to create a dynamic page website using adobe muse design. I mean create a dynamic page of course i will use php, jquery, ajax, framework codeigniter, javascript inside adobe muse html page design.

why i need adobe muse to design web page because it really simple and safe a lot of time for the design.

But the problem here i need php tuh make it dynamic.

i will not just create a simple website. but sometimes i think with adobe muse design i will also create a complete website like marketplace, like a social media maybe.

could someone explain this question ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe Muse isn't for designing dynamic pages but is don't mean you can't, because way Muse make pages, it's very difficult to turn in to dynamic pages and add server side code

Comment: So what adobe muse use for ?.. if only for just design what it use for. it cant be use to anything. Design and cant be sold, design cant be code it.

Comment: Muse mostly uses for static pages and landing pages